# Hide some profile information from Profile Page - Lamba Theme

Tags: css, moodle, profile

I am hoping someone here can help me.

I am using **Moodle 3.8+** with the **Lambda theme** and have a question.

On the Profile Page I would like to be able to remove some elements, usually I would use additional css to set a display: none to various elements but I don't seem to be able to do this here as all the elements are called **contentnode**, any ideas how this can be done?

I would like to remove the "Please verify that you are over the age of 13 years old"

[image: Red Circle]

Any ideas? if I haven't given enough information or if this does not makes sense then please let me know.

Comment: You'll have to share the code wrapping the User details section if you want to go at that by CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site administration > Users > Accounts > User profile fields

Edit the "Please verify ..." field

There is an option for "Who is this field visible to"

[image]

Try changing it to "Visible to user" - this will mean only the user and site admins can see it.